# Unable to create Highchart where i can show different - different data on clicking category and series

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Is it possible to render different data on category clicking and diffrent for series clicking.  for example: 
    http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/drilldown/drillupbutton/

```
$(function () {

    Highcharts.setOptions({
        lang: {
            drillUpText: '<< Terug naar {series.name}'
        }
    });

    // Create the chart
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Drilldown label styling'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'category'
        },

        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                borderWidth: 0,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            }
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Things',
            colorByPoint: true,
            data: [{
                name: 'Dieren',
                y: 5,
                drilldown: 'animals'
            }, {
                name: 'Fruit',
                y: 2,
                drilldown: 'fruits'
            }, {
                name: 'Auto\'s',
                y: 4
            }]
        }],
        drilldown: {

            series: [{
                id: 'animals',
                data: [
                    ['Katten', 4],
                    ['Honden', 2],
                    ['Koeien', 1],
                    ['Schapen', 2],
                    ['Varkens', 1]
                ],
                name: 'vk',
                drilldown : 'vinay'
            }, {
                id: 'fruits',
                data: [
                    ['Appels', 4],
                    ['Sinaasappels', 2]
                ]
            },
            {
                    id: 'vinay',
                data: [
                    ['vinay', 4],
                    ['sharma', 2]
                ]
            }

            ]
        }
    });
});
```

There I am trying to drilldown series on click Dieren column and on Dieren link also.

Comment: No one can answer this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do your chart by using async drilldown. You can find demo of it at Highcharts website. 
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/drilldown/async/

You can load different series as drilldown when you are clicking categories or points, by using the if statement:

```
 if (e.category === undef) {
                  var chart = this,
                    drilldowns = {
                      'Animals': {
                        name: 'Animals',
                        data: [
                          ['Cows', 2],
                          ['Sheep', 3]
                        ]
                      },
                      'Fruits': {
                        name: 'Fruits',
                        data: [
                          ['Apples', 5],
                          ['Oranges', 7],
                          ['Bananas', 2]
                        ]
                      },
                      'Cars': {
                        name: 'Cars',
                        data: [
                          ['Toyota', 1],
                          ['Volkswagen', 2],
                          ['Opel', 5]
                        ]
                      }
                    },
                    series = drilldowns[e.point.name];
                } else {
                  var chart = this,
                    drilldowns = {
                      'Animals': {
                        name: 'Animals',
                        data: [
                          ['Elephants', 5],
                          ['Dogs', 1]
                        ]
                      },
                      'Fruits': {
                        name: 'Fruits',
                        data: [
                          ['Lemons', 1],
                          ['Berries', 4],
                          ['Grapes', 7]
                        ]
                      },
                      'Cars': {
                        name: 'Cars',
                        data: [
                          ['Alfa', 4],
                          ['BMW', 7],
                          ['Citroen', 1]
                        ]
                      }
                    },
                    series = drilldowns[e.point.name];
                }
```

When you are clicking on one of categories e.category is an index of your category. When you will be clicking on point, e.category will be undefined. 
That is the main idea behind my code.

example:
http://jsfiddle.net/u3sa772j/3/